# Is there a way to write the character '\' at all?

Tags: c

I'm currently messing around with printing strings in the console and making them draw functions over time, and while that happened I thought of making the graph more visual by making use of the chars `\|/`. Obviously, it's not that important, but while writing it down in code

```
oscilated[t]='\';
```

the compiler immediately starts complaining, probably due to the char having to do with the `\0` of the string.
So my question is if I can print the char another way, or is it really impossible?

Comment: more info on [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use an escape sequence.

```c
oscilated[t]='\\';
```

Comment: to clarify: the problem is that `\"` is how you write a `"` since otherwise it would be the end of the string. So you can't write `"\"` as a string. But you can write `"\\"` to write a \ in a string. So `"a\\b"` is a string containing a\b. And the same rules apply for character constants.

Comment: Oh, so \ is used to print characters that are used otherwise for formatting right? Thanks alot, hope it wasnt a dumb question.